# Codeigniter Ajax Delete

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to develop a project with codeigniter3. I am trying to delete a data in a table. The table is as follows;

```
<tbody>
  <tr id="1">
   <td>text</td>
   <td>text</td>
   <td>text</td>
   <td>text</td>
   <td><button type="button" id="1"></button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The ajax function that I deleted the data is as follows;

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: base_url+"controller/delete", 
    cache:false,
    data:{[csrfName]:csrfHash,id:id},
    success: 
       function(data){
         $('#tableid tbody tr#'+id).remove();
       }
 });
```

but if the table id is changed manually on the page, it deletes the matching data in the database. For example, if I open the page source, change the button id, and press the button, it deletes the id value I just gave. What should I do to avoid outside interference?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example, if I open the page source, change the button id, and press the button, it deletes the id value I just gave.

This is expected and correct behavior.  The user is manually tinkering with the client-side values in this case and is crafting whatever request they want to the server.  Which the user is entirely allowed to do on their own computer.

Technically the user doesn't even need to use the browser *at all*.  They can just examine the DOM, network requests, etc. and start crafting their own requests in something like Postman.  The server can't tell the difference, nor does it need to.  A request is a request, regardless of what client-side program sent it.

> What should I do to avoid outside interference?

You don't.  Because this isn't "outside interference".  The user may be using the system in an unexpected way, but it's still normal use of the system.

Think about it from the server's perspective.  What is the difference between these two actions?:

1. The user opens the DOM source and manually sets the ID of record B to match the ID of record A.  The user clicks on record B in the UI.  The system deletes record A because that's the ID that was sent; or...
2. The user clicks record A.  The system deletes record A because that's the ID that was sent.

In both cases, from the server's perspective there is zero difference.  The user chose to delete that record, and being permitted to do so the user successfully deleted that record.  In the first scenario they just went about it in a strange and inefficient way.  But so what?  The net result is the same.  The exact same operation was performed on the server and no harm was done.

There's no need to put in a ton of effort to try and prevent the user from manually crafting their own requests to the server.  At best you'd end up with a drastically over-complicated system which succeeds only in *maybe* making it *slightly harder* for the user, but doesn't actually prevent anything.

Any code that's running on the user's computer is at the mercy of the user.  But as long as the server-side code is secure then there's nothing the user can do that they couldn't already do in the UI anyway.

Comment: Tnx david, thank you very much for clearing my confusion. Good luck for daron